# Eletron app not connecting to the internet

Tags: ionic-framework

Am building a damaged property reporting app  with ionic capacitor and angular and firebase's firestore and firestorage as my database the app works's fine as an apk but when i convert it to an eletron app it doesn't connect to the internet it keeps on giving me a network issue error or bad connection

These are the commands i used to build and open the eletron app:

1.npm i @capacitor-community/electron

2.npx cap add @capacitor-community/electron

3.npx cap open @capacitor-community/electron

I checked other apps on my pc and they are connecting fine to the  internet so  the issue is not because of bad connection

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when i did not set up my content security policy you can do that by changing to electron/src/setup.ts to

```
export function setupContentSecurityPolicy(customScheme: string): void {
    const domainsWhiteList:string[] = [
      "https://*yoururl*:*yourport*"
    ];
    session.defaultSession.webRequest.onHeadersReceived((details, callback) => {
      callback({
        responseHeaders: {
          ...details.responseHeaders,
          'Content-Security-Policy': [
            electronIsDev
              ? `default-src ${customScheme}://* 'unsafe-inline' devtools://* 'unsafe-eval' data: ${domainsWhiteList.join(' ')}`
              : `default-src ${customScheme}://* 'unsafe-inline' file://* data: ${domainsWhiteList.join(' ')}`,
          ],
        },
      });
    });
  }
```